# Arduino library creation - Calling library and Merging

Tags: library

I am new to creating a library in Arduino. I was able to create a library from YouTube. I want to merge two other libraries into the library I created. Can you please help me to do so?

I already created a keywords.txt file for my library but the keywords are not getting highlighted in orange in the IDE. But it identifies as keywords.

Please guide me how to properly create a keywords file and merge the libraries.

Keywords below:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Syntax coloring for IotBlueEmon library
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Datatypes (such as objects)
CurrentSense KEYWORD1

#Methods / functions
begin   KEYWORD2
Counter1   KEYWORD2
Counter2   KEYWORD2
counter3   KEYWORD2
getCNT1   KEYWORD2
getCNT2   KEYWORD2
getCNT3   KEYWORD2

# Constants
```

Comment: please delete the comment. it clutters up the post. you have added it correctly to the question. (there is a little red X next to the comment. it shows up when you hover the mouse pointer over the comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you consult the [Arduino Library Specification's section on keywords.txt](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#keywords):

> A tab should be used to separate each name from the KEYWORD1/Keyword2/Literal1 identifier.

A true tab character is required, rather than spaces, as you have in your keywords.txt. It is common for text editors to be configured to add a given number of spaces when the tab key is pressed rather than a true tab character. That's great but in this case you will need to be sure that the tab character is used.

Note that the tab requirement [will be relaxed](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/6693) in the Arduino IDE 1.9.0 release, which will also accept space(s) as a keywords separator but it's still best to use tabs for backwards compatibility since people will be using pre-1.9.0 IDE versions for years to come.